# click specific word link if I have two matched word

Tags: python, selenium

I have Button contain Span with spcfic word like log and I have similar button contain span with word logging when I tried to click the word log it clicked on logging, so I want to click log not logging I used the below code but it clicked on logging only

```
  buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'log')]")
 time.sleep(5)
 for btn in buttons:
     btn.click()
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: done I edited the question

Comment: Can you add the content of list `buttons`?

Answer (score 1):

Try that.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='log']")
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Adding some info: ``[text()='log']`` checks for exact match, whereas ``[contains(text(),'log')]`` will find anything which contains the desired text.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to check `WebElement` attribute text as follows:

```
buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'log')]")
time.sleep(5)
for btn in buttons:
    if btn.text == 'log':
        btn.click()
```

Comment: I tried it and the script finished without any clicks